# Wordpress on SQL 2008 - find and replace string

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just managed to install WordPress on **SQL 2008 R2**. How to **find and replace strings** (URLs) in `dbo.wp_post`s table, `post_content` column?

Looking for a way to replace `http://localhost/` with `http://somedomain.com`

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
UPDATE dbo.wp_post
SET post_content = 
    REPLACE(post_content, 'http://localhost/', 'http://somedomain.com');
WHERE ... --predicatehere
```